# Can't enter "e" into my exponential decay function

Tags: r

I have to write a program to model exponential growth. I entered the following as my formula:

```
expDecay<-function(time,A=3,B=4,k=5){return(A*e^(-k*time)+B)}
```

However, R keeps returning the following message:

> Error: object 'e' not found

Is there any way to get around this? Am I entering it wrong?

Comment: Since `?e` doesn't return a help page, the next thing to try is to search for `?log`... which also documents the `exp` function.

Answer (score 6):

Use `exp()`. In your case, `exp(-k*time)`.

Answer (score 3):

Write `exp(x)` instead of `e^x`:

```
> exp(2)
[1] 7.389056
```

Thus your function would become:

```
expDecay <- function(time,A=3,B=4,k=5) {return(A*exp(-k*time)+B)}
```

Answer (score 3):

you do this to get e:

```
e <- exp(1)
```

Comment: or  use `10^(x*0.4342945)` .  The proof is left to the reader :-)